# Linux Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS: 'Network Unreachable'

Tags: networking, internet

I honestly don't have a clue what the issue is as i'm fairly new to Linux and networking. It was working fine for the past month but now it just doesn't want to connect to the internet at all. I've tried to ping my router, 192.168.1.254 and 8.8.8.8 but they both say network unreachable. 
I tried looking in sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces, but it is just a blank file with nothing in it. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
*-network = DISABLED
description: Ethernet Interface
product: PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Ltd
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
version: 06
serial: c8:60:00:9e:bf:d1
width: 64 bits
clock: 33mhz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list 
ethernet_physical
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8169 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
resources: irq:18 ioport:d000(size=256) memory: f0304000-f0304fff memory: 
f0300000-f0303fff
```

that's what comes out when I type in 'sudo lshw -C network'

This is from cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml

```
network:
  ethernets:
   enp7s0:
    addresses:
    - 192.168.1.200/24
    gateway4: 192.168.1.254
    nameservers:
       addresses:
       -8.8.8.8
       -8.8.4.4
   version: 2
```

Here is what comes out with 'ip a'

```
1: io: <LOOPBACK.UP.LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN grou 
       default qlen 1000
         link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
         inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
         inet6 ::1/128 scope host
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp4s0: <BROADCAST.MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default 
           qlen 1000
            link/ether c8:60:00:9e:bf:d1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: Linux server? Are we talking about "Ubuntu server"? If so, what version is it?

Comment: Sorry, it's Ubuntu Server, 20.04 LTS i believe.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I've edited it to show the results from the commands you listed.

Comment: Thanks for the info, however I need to see the entire output of `sudo lshw -C network`. Also show me `ip a`.

Comment: @heynnema I've edited it and shown the entire output of that command, I've also shown the output of `ip a`

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have two problems.

**.yaml file**

Replace your `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` with my .yaml code. Keep the exact spacing, indentation, and no tabs.

`sudo -H gedit /etc/netplan/*.yaml` # replace the * with the correct filename

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp4s0:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.200/24
      gateway4: 192.168.1.254
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 8.8.4.4
```

Then do:

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot` # mandatory

**link**

"link=no" indicates that an ethernet cable may not be attached.

Comment: @DanielH Glad to hear it! Thanks for the update.

Comment: I was wondering if I could avoid reboot. Thanks for confirming that this was the step I unfortunately needed.

Comment: Note I only had a few lines in my Netplan yaml file (no name servers or addresses) but simply running `netplan generate`, `netplan apply`, reboot fixed the broken internet. Thank you!

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04: "WARNING: `gateway4` has been deprecated, use default routes instead"
not sure what this means or which documentation its referring to

Answer (score 0):

To setup a static ip you need to go to /etc/netplan and there you will see a .yaml file.
Check the configs there, otherwise if you have a firewall, it might be that it is blocking you.(It is what happened to me)

Comment: Did you see my answer? And a firewall problem won't cause this.

Comment: yep I did and you are very right, I wanted to add smth about the firewall.

Comment: As I mention, a firewall problem won't cause this. In this particular case, they had used an incorrect ethernet device ID, and an incorrectly formatted .yaml file.