# accidentially deleted the eth0 item, how can I get it back?

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, system-installation

I am newby to ubuntu, trying to install ubuntu-server 20.04. During my 1st installation, the network was working good. Per my memory, there was a "enxxx" item at Network Connections page, but I deleted it somehow when I was messing with it.

For some reasons, I have to reinstall the system, but this time I can't find the item indicating the ethernet card. Worse, I can't get any tool since no access to the Internet after installation, say, sudo apt-get install ifconfig is impossible.

I hv tried edit the netplan /etc/netplan, as [the answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243500/linux-ubuntu-server-20-04-lts-network-unreachable) suggested. also I'd checked the bios, the mac of the ethernet is there.

Please advise how I can solve this issue, or any hint is most welcome. Thanks.

btw, the newly-installed system even doesn't know `auto` command.

[the regular network connection page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPQSB.png)

Screen when installing
[image: Screen when installing]

result for `ip a`
[image: ip a]

result for `lshw`
[image: lshw]

result for `lspci`
[image: lspci]

I can find the ethernet controller with `sudo lshw -class Net` but can't make it work.

[image: lshw -class Net]

for better understanding, here is my `lshw -c network` and `netplan`

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       version: 11
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:53300000-5331ffff
```

netplan

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Comment: Can you [edit your question] to include the output of `ip a`, `sudo lshw -C network` and `lspci`? This will show hardware and network-related information that may help with an answer.

Comment: @matigo many thanks, pls find the images attached. Seems the ethernet care is there, but I just don't know how to get it working.

Comment: Do you have a physical button in your laptop or a hotkey in your laptop's keyboard to enable/disable the Ethernet/Wifi?. Is it a USB dongle or a dedicated Ethernet port?. Cheers

Comment: @CarlesMateo No, I don't think so, unfortunately.

Comment: @EricHuang please execute this command and paste the output. You should see your Ethernet device in there: ```ls -al /sys/class/net```

Comment: @CarlesMateo only the "lo" soft linked to `../../devices/virtual/net/lo ` , Even I can see it, 
 but I jus can't make it work.

Comment: Are those screenshots from the current running system that has no ethernet? If so, edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and a full output of `sudo lshw -C network`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Mnay thanks! for better reading experience, pls find the edited post. I'd added the content of the files on it.

Comment: @EricHuang when you say that you deleted eth0, what exact command did you execute to make this happen?.

Comment: @EricHuang With little information to go on, please see my initial answer. If it helps to solve the problem, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @CarlesMateo when `ip a` I see nothing, but with `lshw -c network`, I can see it. Assuming that the os sees it, but don' t know how to deal with it, and that should be driver issue.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that you're installing Ubuntu **Server** 20.04...

Confirm that /etc/network/interfaces (if it exists) contains only this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Confirm that /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf contains this:

```
[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

We'll change /etc/netplan/*.yaml...

`cd /etc/netplan` # change directory

`ls -al` # find the filename

`sudo pico the_filename_shown_above.yaml` # edit the file

Change this:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

To this:

```
# Let systemd-networkd manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: true
```

Save the file.

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

Comment: Thanks, my question is that, how can it know the name of the ethernet care is `enp0s3`, since the os only see it at hardware level? one new information. I just checked with gigabyte, the motherboard company, they say they don't provide ubunbtu driver yet, I guess I have to go find it, and work again.

Comment: @EricHuang It would be useful to know how/where you deleted eth0. Then I could come up with a more accurate answer. There is no driver required from GB. Try my .yaml file and see if it works.

Comment: @EricHuang You could also boot to a Ubuntu **Desktop** USB/DVD and see if the ethernet works. If it does, do `sudo lshw -C network` and edit that output into your question.

Comment: @EricHuang Status please...

Comment: @EricHuang Status please...