# Cannot load GUI and connect to internet in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking, gui

My ubuntu virtual system cannot be opened with GUI. I tried to reinstall the ubuntu-desktop but I can't connect the internet.
`ping 8.8.8.8` gave `Network is unreachable` to me.

I'd like to share more information if anyone can help me with this.

[information about network config now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GblgK.png)

I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243500/linux-ubuntu-server-20-04-lts-network-unreachable#comment2096709_1243880) but got `(gedit:3681): Gtk-WARNING **:00:21:29.367: cannot open display:`

Answer (score 0):

Run `startx` . If it fails, connect your android/ios device to your pc with usb and enable usb tethering. That should give your pc an internet access,then run `sudo apt install xorg` . Then re-run `startx`

Once you are in, update the system and reboot.

Comment: This ```startx``` didn't work... But I'm wondering whether this usb connect to my android mobile phone really give internet access in my virtual ubuntu system?

Comment: I tried usb connect. The error is ```usb usb1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device```

Comment: @Spidy I add a png for my network config now

Comment: I tried connect my cellphone again. I got ```usb 1-1: device not accepting address 19, error -110```